# why does tf.case build callable function twice?

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to build multiple branches in a network. So I used tf.case in my code. But I found that tf.case always build the last callable function twice, which would result in the Variable Error: "Variable XXX already exist"(I created variables by slim, the variable scope "case/If_x" wouldn't exist, that's why I would get error). Here is a test program with ouput.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

slim = tf.contrib.slim

def fn1(X, Y):
    with tf.variable_scope("fn1", reuse=False):
       w = tf.Variable(1.0, name="w")
       #w = slim.variable(name="w", shape=())
    return X*w, Y*w

def fn2(X, Y):
    with tf.variable_scope("fn2", reuse=False):
       w = tf.Variable(2.0, name="w")
       #w = slim.variable(name="w", shape=())
    return X*w, Y*w

def fn3(X, Y):
    with tf.variable_scope("fn3", reuse=False):
       w = tf.Variable(3.0, name="w")
       #w = slim.variable(name="w", shape=())
    return X*w, Y*w

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Z = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=())
        self.X = tf.Variable(1.0, name="X")
        self.Y = tf.Variable(2.0, name="Y")

    def build(self):
        self.result = tf.case(
            pred_fn_pairs=[
                    (tf.equal(self.Z, 10), lambda : fn3(self.X, self.Y)),
                    (tf.equal(self.Z, 20), lambda : fn2(self.X, self.Y)),
                    (tf.equal(self.Z, 30), lambda : fn1(self.X, self.Y))],
                    exclusive=False)

test = Test()
test.build()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
    tvars_vals = sess.run(tvars)

    for var, val in zip(tvars, tvars_vals):
        print(var.name) 

    aa = sess.run(test.result, feed_dict={test.Z:20})
    print aa
```

The output is:

```
X:0
Y:0
case/If_0/fn1/w:0
case/If_0/fn1_1/w:0
case/If_1/fn2/w:0
case/If_2/fn3/w:0
(2.0, 4.0)
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue, can u restart your jupyter kernel or python environment and try again, so that the variables will be discarded

Comment: @naveenmarri Which one do you use to create varaible tf.Variable() or slim.variable()?  I tried this program many times in spyder(restarting kernel every time). If I use tf.Variable(), the program can run successfully, with showing fn1 being build twice as I put. If I use slim.variable(). it will get error.